# Slightly diffuse question around the Schwarz-Pick lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose a holomorphic function $f$ from the open right halfplane into itself satisfies
$$ |f(z)| \le M |z|.$$
My feeling is that this growth condition condition should (maybe via the Pick-Schwarz type Lemmata) have some heavy consequence for $f$.

Concrete questions are: does $f$ maybe send the right half plane in fact in some smaller sector $S_\theta = \{ z: \arg(z) \le  \theta < \pi/2\}$ ? More generally, can one relate $\Re(f(z))$ with $|f(z)|$?

Thank you, Eric

Comment: The identity map $f(z)=z$ does not map the halfplane into a smaller sector. Also, $f(z)=z+ic$ has the same real part but different modulus.